# Using fetch to get data from an API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

In Panel.js how can I  get data from an API that I wrote in index.js?

Panel.js
[image]

index.js
[image]

ProfilePanel.js
[image]

Comment: Please edit you question to be more informative to other users in future. Links would be dead.

Comment: Copy paste the code into your question. Images of code aren't so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript fetch API

**GET example**

```
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?key=${key}&results=${results}`)
            .then((res) => { return res.json() })
            .then((data) => { 
                console.log(data)
                });
           })
}
```

**POST example**

```
  let key = 'key'
  let results = 12;

  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers : new Headers(),
      body:JSON.stringify({key: key, results: results})//use property short hand here
  }).then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) =>  console.log(data))
  .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: great example! 
this should be the answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

you already get the response and you map the response to state 'results'.you can dispaly the data by simply writing "this.state.results"